# Check to see if a custom radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I have a series of custom radio buttons and I'm trying to see if it's selecting the correct value to the console. But I'm not 100% sure on how to capture that with `:checked`

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="item">
  <input type="radio" id="advisor-908" name="product_advisor" data-advisor="Jim Bob" data-toggle="advisor">
  <label for="advisor-908"><span class="radial"></span>
    <div class="name">Jim Bob
    </div>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input type="radio" id="advisor-909" name="product_advisor" data-advisor="Sneaky Pete" data-toggle="advisor">
  <label for="advisor-909"><span class="radial"></span>
    <div class="name">Sneaky Pete
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('input[name="product_advisor"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var advisorType = $(this).data("advisor");
    console.log(advisorType);
    e.target

});
```

Eventually, I'm going to store that data attribute into `localStorage` but for now I'm just checking to see if I can get that data value out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the currently checked radio button from another place (unrelated to the event you have posted):

```
$('input[name=product_advisor]:checked').data('advisor')
```

But why aren't you using the `value` of the input, instead of that custom data attribute?

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I could do that instead. I'm trying to refactor something from other bits of other stuff, so I'm not sure at this point of where or what that would possibly conflict with something else...if that makes any sense? Meh, my brain is mush today.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the change event check with `.is()`

```
$('input[name="product_advisor"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
         var advisorType = $(this).data("advisor");
         console.log(advisorType);
    }
});
```

Edit: change event lets you capture changes that weren't borne out of clicks.

Comment: the `name` is `product_advisor` by the way

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

As far as I can tell he wants to get data attributes from the checked radio button when the selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have committed error on script js

Replace this:

```
$('input[name="advisor"]').on('click', function (e) {
var advisorType = $(this).data("advisor");
console.log("advisorType");
e.target
});
```

With:

```
$('input[name="product_advisor"]').on('click', function (e) {
var advisorType = $(this).data("advisor");
console.log(advisorType);
e.target
});
```

quotes on data (advisor) and naming "product_advisor".